# SP: Get 5 random records plus 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to get 5 random records from a table plus a further record based on data from the users preferences as stored in a second table.

Here are the two statements i have created so far:

Gets favourite charity based on key set in TBL_MEMBERS:

SELECT DISTINCT TBL_CHARITIES.* FROM TBL_CHARITIES JOIN TBL_MEMBERS ON TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key = TBL_MEMBERS.members_Favourite WHERE TBL_MEMBERS.members_Id = 16

Gets 5 random charities:

SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TBL_CHARITIES WHERE cha_Active = 'TRUE' AND cha_Key != '1' ORDER BY NEWID();

When used in a stored procedure it only returns the first SELECT statement to my .Net page. How can i combine the two statements whilst ensuring that no results are repeated (Eg the favourite is not present in the 5 random records?

Many Thanks!

---

Ok! So now ive updated things and got the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE web.getRandomCharities ( @tmp_ID bigint --members ID ) AS BEGIN

WITH    q AS
 (
 SELECT  TOP 5 *
 FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
 WHERE   cha_Active = 'TRUE'
         AND cha_Key != '1'
 ORDER BY NEWID()
 )

SELECT * FROM q 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ( 
         SELECT * FROM TBL_CHARITIES WHERE TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key IN 
         ( SELECT members_Favourite FROM TBL_MEMBERS WHERE members_Id = @tmp_ID )        EXCEPT SELECT * FROM q ) tc

END
```

Now i need to be able to the record "cha_Key == '1'" but only if its not the users favourite. Is this possible?

Thanks for everything so far. ITs truly appreciated.

Comment: Result of both SELECT statements should be returned to your .NET app. You need to use DataSet and the results are stored in DataSet.DataTables.

Comment: How do i ORDER BY TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key ?

Comment: It is preferred that you just edit your original question with more details. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7771/is-this-abuse-or-misunderstanding-of-the-way-things-work

Comment: I realised that, and updated it shortly afterwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `UNION ALL` them:

```
 WITH    q AS
         (
         SELECT  TOP 5 *
         FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
         WHERE   cha_Active = 'TRUE'
                 AND cha_Key != '1'
         ORDER BY NEWID()
         )
 SELECT  *
 FROM    q
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  TOP 1 *
 FROM    (
         SELECT  *
         FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
         WHERE   TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key IN
                 (
                 SELECT  members_Favourite
                 FROM    TBL_MEMBERS
                 WHERE   members_Id = 16
                 )
         EXCEPT
         SELECT  *
         FROM    q
         ) tc
```

**Update:**

Unfortunately, the query above will not work as intended, since `CTE`'s are reevaluated in `SQL Server`, and the second instance of `q` will give different records.

See this post in my blog for more detail:

- [**`SQL Server`: random records avoiding `CTE` reevaluation**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/28/sql-server-random-records-avoiding-cte-reevaluation/)

You need to rewrite the query as this:

```
 WITH    q AS
         (
         SELECT  TOP 5 *
         FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
         WHERE   cha_Active = 'TRUE'
                 AND cha_Key != '1'
         ORDER BY
                 NEWID()
         ),
         r AS
         (
         SELECT  *
         FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
         WHERE   TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key IN
                 (
                 SELECT  members_Favourite
                 FROM    TBL_MEMBERS
                 WHERE   members_Id = 16
                 )
         )
 SELECT  TOP 6 *
 FROM    q
 FULL OUTER JOIN
         r
 JOIN    TBL_CHARITIES t
 ON      t.id = COALESCE(q.id, r.id)
 ORDER BY
         q.id
```

, assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `TBL_CHARITIES`.

Comment: This doesn't handle the 'no duplicates' part of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pulling down a list of IDs to your .Net page and use your background code to randomly select N number of IDs and pass that as a parameter to your query. You can exclude the user's favorite by using `where id != BL_MEMBERS.members_Favourite` in the query which retrieves the existing IDs,.

This allows you to increase/decrease the number of randomly selected items fairly easily and moves the random generation and checks for unique items to .Net where it is accomplished much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM    (
         SELECT  TOP 5 *
         FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
         WHERE   cha_Active = 'TRUE'
                 AND cha_Key != '1'
         AND cha_Key not in(SELECT  TBL_MEMBERS.members_Favourite
            WHERE   TBL_MEMBERS.members_Id = 16)
         ORDER BY NEWID()
         ) q
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  TOP 1 TBL_CHARITIES.*
 FROM    TBL_CHARITIES
 WHERE   TBL_CHARITIES.cha_Key IN
         (
         SELECT  TBL_MEMBERS.members_Favourite
         FROM    TBL_MEMBERS
         WHERE   TBL_MEMBERS.members_Id = 16
         )
```

Comment: Adding condition into the first query restricts the set beyond what the `@op` is asking for. Random `cha_Key` can be a favourite as well, that's the whole point of constraining the second set.

Comment: And you didn't fix the `FROM` clause when copying the query ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Stored Procedure with a parameter @Memeber_ID.

Then do the type of code that Quassnoi said with a some modifications.

So, pull the top 5 records, but add a join to TBL_MEMBERS and where clause that the records pulled can't be that's memeber_ID's selection. Then do a UNION to that members selection.